# C# launch power options

Tags: c#, launch, controlpanel

From my C# program I want to open the power options from the control panel in Windows.

However I can't seem to find out how to do that, I tried making a shortcut and see where it goes but it is referring to the control panel.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that or where the exe is located to launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("powercfg.cpl");
```

Comment: Thank you this solved it, made it like this: `System.Diagnostics.Process powerProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
powerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "powercfg.cpl";
powerProcess.Start();`